# Using multiple development environments on the same OSX machine?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, django, macos

I have recently got a new Mac (2015 MBP with 8gb ram) and I am trying to set up a development environment using 5 different stacks at the same time.

- I've previously used a **LAMP** set up very similar to [this](https://mallinson.ca/osx-web-development/) - many of my old (client) projects are still based on a PHP MVC framework which uses Foundation and Libsass. While I don't want to make new projects in this way as I want to learn more, I still need to be able to maintain these other projects quickly and easily.
- I then had some data projects in **Python / Django**. On my old mac I used a linux VM through Virtual Box for this (I don't yet own parallels etc).
- I've also trying to learn to use the **MEAN stack** using gulp, browserify and playing around with React JS, as well as **Meteor** (which has it's own server too) and **Ruby on Rails** - and I want to do more development with these, but without losing the ability to work on my other projects.

My problem is that whenever I previously switched to using MEAN or Rails, I messed up my file watching / auto compiling for LAMP and Python and it took me ages to switch back. I really like how browserify works - e.g. to auto compile sass files / minify, and auto refresh the page, but I've hit problems with keeping my python server and lamp set up doing the same. I'm clearly doing something wrong and I'm keen to set this up properly with a clean install. All the tutorials I can find online refer to setting up individual stack environments, but I can't find much which refers to setting them up together.

I've decided that running a separate VM for each different stack would knock performance too much, and there are some things which I'd want to use on more than one stack like homebrew.

**As such, my question is what are the specific advantages of using something like docker to keep things separate vs finding a way using something like homebrew to set up everything together on a single OS?**

I'm aware file watching isn't so easy on docker with virtualbox - but I'm not sure whether to push through and find a work around or to use another way.

Thanks so much - I've been stuck on this for ages. I'm sorry if my question isn't very clear - I'm new to using node / meteor and ruby so I'm not sure the best place to start!

Comment: Hi Simeon. This is a really interesting and well-presented question... unfortunately it isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow :( S/O works best for specific, technical questions that have a "right answer". It doesn't work so well for "is this the best way" questions. In the past we used to allow these kinds of questions, and we had discussion, and discussion led to opinions which led to flame wars, which tore apart our community... so now we just don't allow them any more sorry :( Perhaps try your local ruby-users group?

Comment: Thanks - that's fair enough. Would it be too opinion based to ask what all the 'different ways' of doing it are, or instead to some isolated questions about the specific pros and cons of each possible way about which I'm aware?

Comment: Isolated questions will work fine - I'd try to ask myself "is there one right answer to this?" for each of them to see if they fit well here - it's a good rule of thumb to avoid the opinionated-question thingy...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my humble opinion the best solution by far is to use [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/). It's also free.

Not only that you can have a different environment for each project, but you can also script all the custom installations and configurations. You, or a colleague of yours, will be able to replicate the environment with a simple command, `vagrant up`.

A popular guide for setting up [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) for RoR development can be found [here](https://gorails.com/guides/using-vagrant-for-rails-development). However, contrary to that guide, I gave up using `Chef` in favor of a simple provision script. A guide can be found [here](https://www.dev-metal.com/super-simple-vagrant-lamp-stack-bootstrap-installable-one-command/).

Make sure to enable NFS though, else VirtualBox (Vagrant sits on top of it) will be quite slow.

While solutions like [Cloud9](https://c9.io) or [Koding](https://koding.com) are surely useful for when you do not have access to your development machine, I wouldn't use them for day to day work.

Comment: Just to chip in again here - Thanks for this answer. I have been using vagrant for the last 4 years and this answer really pointed me in the right direction.